# What is the time unit for "datadelay" attribute on GoogleFinance?

Tags: google-sheets, time, delay, google-finance

I'm using the GoogleFinance() functions on a Google spreadsheet to keep track of my stocks. With the "datadelay" attribute I can check how long ago the data has been updated for the last time. But it only returns a raw number, like "54000" for one ticker and "15" for another. What time unit is that supposed to be? minutes? seconds? milliseconds?

Answer (score 1):

When I check the documentation for the Google Finance I saw that there is a page explains there might be delay up to 20 minutes. They also mentioned that they are using different exchanges to retrieve market data and all this different exchanges might have different data delay. It can explain the differences in the "datadelay" column.

For the unit of this column, my assumption is it should be shorter than seconds since 54000 seconds = 900 min, which is far higher than the maximum delay defined in the help page. But I am not sure what would be value for this column when you query in the not-trading days.

The  [page](https://www.google.com/googlefinance/disclaimer/#!#realtime) shows delays for each exchange.

Answer (score 0):

`GoogleFinance()` function updates every minute (if it is set so), but keep in mind that results may be delayed up to 20 minutes. so the answer is between 1-20 minutes